# New message taking time to load on recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am creating a chat application using Firebase. It works fine. But sometimes it's taking 3-4 sec time to display on a recyclerview.

In log it shows,

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

But I don't think I have much operations happening in the main thread

You can see my Recyclerview code there:

https://pastebin.com/njTH6y2b

But when i send message, it doesn't take time. It loads instantly on other device. But I get that delay sometimes on other phones too..

So where am I doing wrong.

Please I need help in this issue so much. I tried so much for finding the reason and solution. But I failed. Please :(

Answer (score 0):

A reason that slows down your chat application is that your main thread is running to many loops with to many objects. However, not knowing what exactly you are executing in your code, keep in mind that is just an opinion.

I suggest you try to reduce the numeber of loops and the number of objects (if possible), make a test and see the results.

Hope it helps.